# How to add non animated text in blender video editing easily

Tags: video

All I've found on the internet are animated ways to add text and a tutorial that is now outdated. Is there any other way then just creating it as a 2D object in the editor?

Answer (score 1):

In video sequence editor, press shift-A then select text, or in the header Add>Text

Is this what you are looking for? 
Image from https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/sequencer/strips/text.html
[image: Text in video sequence editor]